# Вопрос по верстке. Как сделать такое?

Tags: html, вёрстка, display

Как сделать чтобы было четко по центру, но справа был блок, который немного вылазит ? Без всяких костылей. Получается сделать так только если контейнеру где лежат фотки, указать margin-left какой-то. Но это просто костыль, и оно не всегда будет ровно

[image: Блоки]

Comment: Опиши подробнее для чего предназначен данный блок, там всегда только 2 изображения или это вообще слайдер?  

И прикрепляй пожалуйста пример кода к своему вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте центральному сделать `margin: 0 auto;`, а правый подвинуть `margin`'ом левую сторону.

Либо центральный сделать по ширине `100%`, а правый край двигай `margin`'ом... тогда правая картинка сдвинется относительно его стороны куда надо.

В общем, `margin` решает многое, на курсах обычно говорят, что это просто отступ, но это же еще и граница соединение соседних элементов.

Ещё вариант через `display:flex;` попробовать.

Comment: Не пойму, чего можно добиться задавая свойства описанные в твоем ответе, блоки всегда будут на разных строках.
Прикрепляй примеры кода пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот пример, получается.. наверное через position: absolute; более красиво..но это тоже работает)) так обычно удобно подвинуть под картинку текст или элемент
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wNqwjd 


 <div style="background-color: aliceblue; width:500px; height:800px"> 
  <div style="background-color: black; width:40px; margin:0 auto; height:400px"></div> 
  <div style="background-color: blue; width:40px; height:400px; margin: -365px 0 0 460px;"></div>
  <div style="background-color: green; width:100%; margin:0 auto; height:400px"></div> 
 </div>

Comment: Данная реализация не очень хорошая, т.к. работает с фиксированными значениями, а при изменении высоты блока или ширины контейнера все сломается. Можно немного ее улучшить, сделав второму блоку matgin-left: auto; так хотя бы он будет всегда прижат к правому краю не зависимо от ширины.

Answer (score 0):

Всё, я решил свою проблему. Нужно было добавить третий блок, тогда бы у меня средний блок стал по центру, а первому блоку дать opacity 0, и всё стало правильно

Comment: можно расположить первый блок по центру любым удобным способом, а второй блок при помощи position: absolute; прижать к правому краю и сдвинуть вправо на 50% ширины при помощи transfrom или margin.